# Build error while building Flutter in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

When I run `flutter build iOS`I get the following error:

[image]

Steps I've tried:

- `flutter clean`
- `flutter  pub get`
- Deleted `Podfile.lock`

**Note**: Android builds successfully

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest version of Xcode & try to build from Xcode to get more detailed error